# How to draw a standard normal distribution in R

Tags: r, plot, distribution, draw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a standard normal distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488988/making-a-standard-normal-distribution-in-r)

> Using R, draw a standard normal distribution. Label the mean and 3 standard deviations above and below the (10) mean. Include an informative title and labels on the x and y axes.

This is a homework problem. I'm not sure how to get going with the code. How should I get started?

Comment: Alright I made some changes to it, but now how would I go about marking 3 standard deviations above and below the mean? `plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=1,main="Mean of a Standard Normal Distribution",xlab="X",ylab="Y") abline(a=10,b=1,v=10)`

Comment: `data=rnorm(1e4, mean=10, sd=3)`, then `plot(density(data))` and add normal curve : `curve(dnorm(x, mean=10, sd=3), add=TRUE, col=3)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489547/1317221). Anyway, have a look at the following piece of code

```
x <- seq(5, 15, length=1000)
y <- dnorm(x, mean=10, sd=3)
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=1)
```

I'm sure you can work the rest out yourself, for the title you might want to look for something called `main=` and `y-axis` labels are also up to you.

If you want to see more of the tails of the distribution, why don't you try playing with the `seq(5, 15, )` section? Finally, if you want to know more about what `dnorm` is doing I suggest you look [here](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/prob.html)

Comment: Alright I made some changes to it, but now how would I go about marking 3 standard deviations above and below the mean?             `> plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=1,main="Mean of a Standard Normal Distribution",xlab="X",ylab="Y")
> abline(a=10,b=1,v=10)`

Comment: make `seq(0,20,length=1000)` so you see more of the curve. Now one standard deviation in my code is 3 right? i.e. `sd=3` so three standard deviations above 10 and below should be 1 and 19: `abline(a=1,b=1,v=19)` and `abline(a=1,b=1,v=1)`

Comment: data=rnorm(1e4, mean=10, sd=3), then plot(density(data)) and add normal curve : curve(dnorm(x, mean=10, sd=3), add=TRUE, col=3)  using `seq` is unnecessary

Answer (score 7):

By the way, instead of generating the *x* and *y* coordinates yourself, you can also use the `curve()` function, which is intended to draw curves corresponding to a function (such as the density of a standard normal function).

see

```
help(curve)
```

and its examples.

And if you want to add som text to properly label the mean and standard deviations, you can use the `text()` function (see also `plotmath`, for annotations with mathematical symbols) .

see

```
help(text)
help(plotmath)
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this perhaps?

```
x<-rnorm(100000,mean=10, sd=2)
hist(x,breaks=150,xlim=c(0,20),freq=FALSE)
abline(v=10, lwd=5)
abline(v=c(4,6,8,12,14,16), lwd=3,lty=3)
```