# How I can fix my variant of standard normal distribution in R?

Tags: r

I would like to draw such plot of standard normal distribution with 100000 tryings:

[image]

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488988/how-to-plot-a-normal-distribution-by-labeling-specific-parts-of-the-x-axis/10489547#10489547) question also. But I didn't see any solutions for my task. So I created my own variant which is based on different websites and books. My solution didn't have `F(x)` which I would like to see. Below you can see my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(x)/sum(abs(x)))/2.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density"))
```

and its look:

[image]

I can't understand how to fix the blue line and also I can't understand why I have to use `2.5` at my code. Maybe my variant is tottale wrong? How I can draw my desired distribution?

Comment: If you want to plot the standard normal, why do you plot a kernel density estimate from a sample? Do you want to compare the kernel density estimate with the true density function?

Comment: `ggplot(data.frame(x =c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, color = "dark blue", size = 2) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) pnorm(x) * 0.4, color = "purple", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / 0.4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several solutions for this. This is my effort, only changed one line in your code: `cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))/2.5) %>%`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))/2.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density"))
```

[image]
About why use 2.5, I am strugglling to work it out every time I use second y axis. First, let's look at if what this graph look like without 2.5 in `cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))) %>%` and `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "cumulative density"))`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "cumulative density"))
```

You get the following graph 
[image]

To shrink the second y axis, we re-scale the second y: `cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))/2.5)`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = sort(rnorm(1e5)),
       cumulative = cumsum(abs(5-x)/sum(abs(5-x)))/2.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 500)+
  geom_density(color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(y = cumulative), color = "navy")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "cumulative density"))
```

We get the following graph:

[image]

1/2.5 = 0.4 The maximum values for both axis now are similar.

I think `ggplot` using these rescaled values to generate the graph, and then we label them by multiplying those values by 2.5 in `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2.5, name = "cumulative density"))`.

Sorry for this long answer. I am not sure if I have made it clear. Others may explain it better.

Comment: can you please explain about 2.5 more clearly, because I still can't understand :(

Comment: Tricky to explain it in words. We will try to revise my answer with graphs.